# checkPermission() is in error in my activity file

Tags: kotlin

[image: Code]
[image: Code]

I am trying to get the current latitude and longitude for my final year project, but the `checkPermission()` function is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `checkPermission()` function that is declared in your Kotlin class.

You would create this class like this (returning a bool, because of your function call being placed into a conditional)

```
private fun checkPermission() : Bool {
    // your code here
    return true // Either true or false will be passed to your conditional when called
}
```